# How is measure() testing normally use for in performance unit testing?

Tags: swift, xcode, unit-testing, cocoa, performance-testing

I found boilerplate of Unit Test file has performance test. I tried to put a function inside but it doesn't seems like it works in that way. My question is:

1. Why we need this performance test and when its useful to use?
2. How is the best practice of doing performance test?

   func testPerformanceExample() {
       self.measure {
       }
   }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Sometimes we need to test the performance of specific functions. e.g. Encrypt and compress a big file; load big data; process image and video; internet operation etc. Performance test will be very useful to check the time consuming for a task.
2. First of all, you need to set baseline for comparing each operating time. The default tolerance is 10% of baseline which means if the operating time is more than 10% of baseline, then the test would not pass. You can change the tolerance to any percentage depends on your case.
3. You can also check all the performance reports from here: Navigator->Click last tab called show the report navigator->Select one test->You can see all the test report including performance and coverage of unit test.

[image]